# Quantum mechanics question?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

A particle of mass $m$ is confined within an infinite, one-dimensional potential well, $U(x)$, of width $a$.
$$
U(x) = \begin{cases}
         \infty  & x \leq \frac{-a}{2}, x \leq \frac{a}{2}\\[6pt]
        0 & \frac{-a}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{a}{2}
    \end{cases}
$$

I have to find the normalised solutions of the time-independent Schrodinger equation.

I know that if it were $0 \leq x \leq a$ rather than $\frac{-a}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{a}{2}$, the solution would be given by $\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})$.
So to find the solution when it is $\frac{-a}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{a}{2}$, do you just replace $a$ with $a/2$ in the solution?

Comment: You should post to : http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Second comment: no, you don't change $a$ with $\frac a2$... the conditions to the limits won't be good...

Comment: Hint: $\frac{-a}{2} \le x \le \frac{a}{2} \iff 0 \le x + \frac{a}{2} \le a$

Comment: check if replacing $sin$ by $cos$ satisfies the equation.

Comment: You just shift: if $f(x)$ is a solution on $[b,c]$ then $f(x+d)$ is a solution on $[b-d,c-d]$. This will work in any autonomous equation. In your situation $b=0,c=a,d=a/2$.

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186493/2451